# HYPERLINK not working in an embedded Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to embed a Google sheet where you can click on an image and it'll take you to a URL via link. Simple enough.

I've tried inserting the image in a cell (let's call that A1) and putting the link in B1 and using the formula =HYPERLINK(B1,A1). That works in the Google sheet itself, but when I embed that Google Sheet on a website (via iFrame), the image is there but the link is not. BUT, when I embed that same sheet as an editable Google sheet via iFrame, the link works.

As far as I can tell, the only difference in the iFrame code is the part that makes it editable.

What am I missing?

I also tried having the HYPERLINK() function reference the image using the IMAGE() function, but no luck.

It DOES work when the HYPERLINK() function uses a text string instead of an image, which makes me think it isn't a "view only" thing.

There's no scripts or coding, just a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding  `?forceEdit=true` to the end of the iFrame's src URL. This could refresh the embedded sheet and potentially activate the image link.